# Modify foreach loop for social sharing links?

Tags: array, get-template-part, social-sharing

How would I amend the following `foreach` loop so each link displays the **keys** from each nested query, and not just the **values**? I am creating my own social sharing links, included using get-template-part, and very nearly have it, I think.

E.g. Twitter currently returns: https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?TITLE&PERMALINK
Instead of: https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=TITLE&url=PERMALINK (Note: text= and url= )

I have tried `( $social_links as $key => $value )` and
`( $social_links as $social_link && $social_link as $key => $value )`

Neither of which is obviously correct.

```
<?php
    // Setup the links
    $social_links = array(
        'facebook'  => array(
            'title' => 'Facebook',
            'base'  => 'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php',
            'query' => array(
                'u'     => get_permalink(),
                't'     => get_the_title(),
            ),
        ),
        'twitter'   => array(
            'title' => 'Twitter',
            'base'  => 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet',
            'query' => array(
                'text'  => get_the_title(),
                'url'   => get_permalink(),
            ),
        ),

        'pinterest' => array(
            'title' => 'Pinterest',
            'base'  => 'http://www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/',
            'query' => array(
                'url'         => get_permalink(),
                'media'       => get_the_post_thumbnail_url(),
                'description' => get_the_title(),
            ),
        ),
        'linked-in' => array(
            'title' => 'LinkedIn',
            'base'  => 'https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle',
            'query' => array(
                'mini'  => 'true',
                'url'   => get_permalink(),
                'title' => get_the_title(),
            ),
            // append '?refresh' to force new scrape
        ),              
    );
?>

<ul class="links-social">
<?php 
    // Loop through the links
    foreach( $social_links as $social_link ) : ?>
        <li>
            <a target="_blank" href="<?php echo $social_link['base']  . '?' . implode( '&', $social_link['query'] ); ?>">
                <?php echo $social_link['title']; ?>
            </a>
        </li>
<?php   
    endforeach;
?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue has nothing to do with the `foreach`. The problem is this part:

```
implode( '&', $social_link['query'] )
```

`implode()` only connects the values. There's nothing in this code that adds the keys or an `=`.

If you want to add an array of key/values as a query string to a URL, WordPress provides a function for this called [`add_query_arg()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_query_arg/), it accepts an array of key values and a URL to add them to.

In your case you'd use it like this:

```
<a target="_blank" href="<?php echo esc_url( add_query_arg( $social_link['query'], $social_link['base'] ) ); ?>">
    <?php echo $social_link['title']; ?>
</a>
```

Note my use of `esc_url`. As [the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_query_arg/) states:

```
Important: The return value of add_query_arg() is not escaped by default. Output should be late-escaped with esc_url() or similar to help prevent vulnerability to cross-site scripting (XSS) attacks.
```

Another thing to consider is that the values in the query string need to be URL encoded. You can do this with the `urlencode()` PHP function:

```
'title' => urlencode( get_the_title() ),
```

However you'll need to do this for every value if you do it like that. A way do to this with less code would be to use [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to apply `urlencode()` to every value just before putting into `add_query_arg()`:

```
foreach( $social_links as $social_link ) :
    $query_args = array_map( 'urlencode', $social_link['query'] );
    ?>

    <li>
        <a target="_blank" href="<?php echo esc_url( add_query_arg( $query_args, $social_link['base'] ) ); ?>">
            <?php echo $social_link['title']; ?>
        </a>
    </li>

    <?php
endforeach;
```

Comment: I'd not come across `add_query_arg()` before, thanks Jacob!  One slight concern, from my code, is that titles are returned with spaces. Do you happen to know of a way to introduce "%" or something similar to the string?

Comment: I've updated my answer.